# Capture form data in an Object on submit

Tags: javascript, object

I have a problem. I don't have much experience with object oriented javascript.
I would like my form to submit details such as first and second name to an object I have created

**This is my object:**

```
      function Person(fname,sname){
        this.fname=fname;
        this.sname=sname;   

        this.confirm = function(){
            alert('Thank you '+this.fname +'<br>'+ this.sname + ' Your email has been recieved');
        }

    function submit(){
        person1= new Person(document.getElementById('fname').value, document.getElementById('sname').value);
person1.confirm();
    }
```

and my form:

```
<input type="text" id="fname" value="First Name"/></br>
<input type="text" id="sname" value="Surname"/></br>
<input type="text" value="Email Address"/></br>
<input type="Submit" value="Submit" onSubmit="submit()"/>
```

Please if someone can help me to get this to work I would appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you assigning an onClick handler to a function used as a constructor? I'd start by reading a more basic tutorial or a book like eloquent JavaScript (free).

Comment: What specifically is not working?

Comment: I need this to work without PHP, This may be wrong completly but my goal is to have the first and second name sent to my object once the form is submited to create a new Person and for an alert to appear using these details as confirmation that it has been submitted

Comment: you need to store it somewhere. so you need a serverside language like php.where do you wanna store the person data?javascript forgets everything as soon as you close the page.

Comment: ive updated original post this is what ive got so far hope im onthe right track thanks for help

Comment: You need parentheses when creating an object: `var person1=new Person();`. You can use it like that and set the properties afterwards (but adding the `value` property to your code, and changing the second `fname` to `sname`), but as you have parameters in the constructor, you should use them instead: `var person1=new Person(document.getElementById('fname').value, document.getElementById('sname').value);`.

Comment: ok ive did this but some some reason it wont alert

Comment: updated original post

Answer (score 1):

You need a `new` for a constructor, so I think you'll want something like this

```
var person=new Person("John","Doe");
person.confirm();
```

However, if you don't want to use `new`, you can do this

```
function Person(fname,sname){
    var wrapper={
                 fname:fname,
                 sname=sname,
                confirm:function(){
                     alert('Thanks you '+this.fname +'<br>'+ this.sname + ' Your email has been recieved');
                }
    return wrapper
```

}

Comment: ive updated original post this is what ive got so far hope im onthe right track thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

To create an instance of the object in the event handler from data in the form, you use syntax like this:

```
<input type="Submit" value="Submit" onSubmit="var p = new Person(document.getElementById('fname').value, document.getElementById('sname').value);"/>
```

Once you have create the object, you naturally have to do something with it to make anything happen, for example calling `p.confirm();`.

---

#### Edit:

To put the code in a function, as per your edit:

```
function submit() {
  var p = new Person(document.getElementById('fname').value, document.getElementById('sname').value);
  p.confirm();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to invoke a Constructor function, you need the `new` keyword
2. If you want to run a method on it, then you need to explicitly call it.
3. If you want to get data from a form, then you must access the DOM objects representing the form controls and read their `value` proeprties

e.g.

```
var person = new Person(
                        document.getElementById('fname').value,
                        document.getElementById('sname').value
                       );
person.confirm();
```

Comment: ive updated original post this is what ive got so far hope im onthe right track thanks for help